# Why do the force get bigger as the angle of roof get bigger?

Tags: forces, air

I am doing this experiment at school to find out how the surface area of roof and angle affect on the wind force applied on the roof. My results show that the force gets bigger as the angle and surface area of the roof get bigger but I don't really understand why.

Comment: If you're on an incline , then dissociate the weight into perpendicular components ... The component acting downwards along the incline of roof is $mgsin\alpha$ ... where $\alpha$ is inclination with base of roof ... As $\alpha$ increases , the force component  increases too

Comment: why does force get bigger when the area gets bigger then?

Comment: The force on the roof is due to collisions of the molecules in the air with the roof, that is the component of the force that is directed into the roof. Think of it this way, the steeper the angle the more of the collision is directly against the roof than along it

Answer (score 0):

Think about the force the wind applies as resulting from collisions between particles in the air and the roof. The number of collisions will be proportional to the surface area of the roof, and the more collisions, the more force applied.